# Moving image with a document click

Tags: jquery, html, image, events, animation

Well I have succeeded in moving three images simultaneously with a single click on the document but I am trying to set it so I can control each image seperately. I'm sort of lost on how do accomplish this, i just started last month

```
var $follower = $(".follower"),
  mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

$(document).click(function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
   $follower.stop().animate({
      left: mouseX,
      top: mouseY
  });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hatsand/S4TfC/210/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following snippet:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S4TfC/215/)

```
var $follower = $(".follower").on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
}),
    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;

$(document).click(function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    $follower.filter('.selected').stop().animate({
        left: mouseX,
        top: mouseY
    });
});
```

Comment: ok there we go i was trying to something like this for the last hour but couldnt get it quite right  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S4TfC/211/

.js

```
$('.follower').click(function (e) {
mouseX = e.pageX;
mouseY = e.pageY;
$(this).stop().animate({
    left: mouseX,
    top: mouseY
});
});
```

This will move each one individually . . .
Basically it's one listener for each instantiation of 'follower' and the 'this' references the 'follower' that was clicked.

Comment: well it does control them but it reverses the event, now it's controlled by clicking the image instead of the document

Comment: If you're clicking the document then the JS has no way of knowing which one you want to move. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: no thats what I was wondering how would I control each with a document click i am thinking it would involve first clicking the image you would like to select and then clicking the document to move it.

for example i guess it would involve the use of binding a function to the image from what im reading with the use of .on and off maybe?

Comment: @CoreyBuchillon that the only possible way which I think you can achieve for your OP. `click\select` the image which you want to move and `click` on the document to move it.

Comment: And you'd have to ensure that the second click wasn't on another image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ID selector.

```
$("#boat").click(function(){
  alert('This is boat!');
});
```

Or assign an event to each element in the array of length `$follower.length` or http://api.jquery.com/each/

A good idea to handle all after the page loads http://api.jquery.com/ready/